# I meet a problem when I am trying to convert a large amount json files into csv

Tags: python, pandas

I have to convert json files as I said, here is the code:enter image description here

```
def AnalysisJson():
    
    file_path = 'my_file'
    
    for root,dirs,files in os.walk(file_path):  
        
        for file in files: 
            
            InputPath = open(file_path + '\\'+ file, encoding="utf-8")
            
            for i in files:
                
                df = json.load(InputPath)
                
                demo = pd.json_normalize(df,record_path = 'label_annotations')
                
                demo.to_csv('files.csv')
```

```
JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

I want to convert these files, if the code is surely hard to run, I wish someone will give me an advice, thanks!

Comment: Can you make your question more concice and provide with an example of the content of the file that you are trying to convert?

Comment: I am trying to convert json into csv, and it was working when I convert single file, but it failed when I handle large mount. Files are too long to upload :(

Comment: How are the JSON files stored? What does the directory structure look like? Are all JSON files stored in the same directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure that I understand correctly what you want, but here is an answer based on my interpretation of your question.

```py
import json
import os
from glob import glob

import pandas as pd


def json_to_csv(dir_path: str) -> None:
    for file_path in glob(os.path.join(dir_path, '*.json')):
        with open(file_path, encoding='utf-8') as f:
            data = json.load(f)
        df = pd.json_normalize(data, record_path='label_annotations')
        df.to_csv(file_path.replace('.json', '.csv'), index=False)
```

Comment: thanks for you helping, I tryed your code, maybe I have not describe my problem clearly, it still can not work, but still thanks for your kindness

Comment: Actually I am a beginner for python, so it is really common for me to see mistakes:(

Comment: How are the JSON files stored? What does the directory structure look like? Are all JSON files stored in the same directory?

Comment: It is a nested structure json files, and they are stored in a same directory. The code you presented above could work, but I want them to convert into many single csv files, instead of merge into one

Comment: So you want each CSV file having a single row?

Comment: I adjusted my answer according to your last comment.

Comment: Actually, not in a single row, but in a single csv files, each json files convert to a new csv files.

Comment: I am really so sorry to say, but it still not work properly, and I have wasted your so many time, it is embarrassing for me to ask again, if you still want to help me, I will show my email, if you not, it is all right, still thanks for your time.
my eamil: yixin.zhang1126@gmail.com